# replacing html content with modified value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I need some expert advice.

The project I'm working on is report generated in HTML.
I need to use javascript to
 1. Find a number and extract a part of it
 2. Increment/Decrement the extracted part
 3. Replace the number with new value
 4. Replace other elements

Also, the html I'm working with has no tags or ids, so I'm forced to grab the entire content.

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/y6Hy7/3/

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = els[i];
  var txt = els[i].textContent; //grabbing the text
  var patt = /\d+(?=,[0-9]{3}\sPARTS)/g; //regex pattern only grab the first 2 digits
  var res = patt.exec(txt); //execute regex on text
  if (res !== null) { //see if its not null
    var toNum = parseInt(res,10) +10;
  } //convert to int and add some fixed value
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(patt, toNum); //replace the original
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace("text need to be changed and looped", "replaced");
}
```

It works, but keep increasing the replaced value too many times. How can I fix that?

Comment: "html I'm working with have no **tags**" - wait, what..?

Comment: Let me rephrase that, no tags I can grab with getElementsByTagName, it basically <html> <head> <body>, and <p> and some tables, other than that, no ID, or other formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find only p tags Not for All

Do like

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = els[i];
  var txt = els[i].textContent; //grabbing the text
  var patt = /\d+(?=,[0-9]{3}\sPARTS)/g; //regex pattern
  var res = patt.exec(txt); //execute regex on text
    if (res !== null) { //see if its not null
    var toNum = parseInt(res,10) +10; } //convert to int and add 10
 el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(patt, toNum); //replace the original
 el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace("text need to be changed and looped", "replaced");

  }
```

if you find all elements using TagName("*"). the els array looks like

```
[html, head, meta, title, script, link, style, script, body, p, p, p, p, p]
```

so loop executed 14 times.

if you still want to use this collect all the elements and remove First 9 elements from it.

like

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
els.splice(0,9)
alert(els);
```

Now els contains only remaining Elements.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6Hy7/5/)

Comment: Yes, but it sometimes in <BR> tag, or not even in <p>, tho i can actually grab element inside BODY that prevent the script to loop trough itself.

Comment: find var els1 = document.getElementsByTagName("br"); now combine els=els+els1;